# Error bound in the P.N.T. under some R.H.-like assumption

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

In lecture notes, there was an exercice that I struggle with. Here, $\psi$ denotes the [Chebychev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function). I assumed that $$\psi(x)-x\in o(x^{1-\varepsilon})$$
for some $0<\varepsilon<1/2$ (which would come from a less strong version of the Riemann Hypothesis, that is some zero-free region of the form $\{\sigma>c\}$). By using summation by parts, I wrote $$\pi(x)=\frac{\psi(x)}{\log(x)}+\int_2^x\frac{\psi(t)}{t\log^2(t)}\text{d}t,$$
which allowed me to prove that $$\pi(x)-\text{Li}(x)\in O(x^{1-\varepsilon}).$$

Now, in the rest of the exercice, I'm asked to prove that $$\pi(x)-\frac{x}{\log(x)}\notin o(x^{1-\delta})$$
for any $\delta>0$ (this is the sense in which $\text{Li}(x)$ is a better approximation to $\pi(x)$ than simply $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$). **How to prove this ?**

If I assume the converse, that is, $$\pi(x)-\frac{x}{\log(x)}\in o(x^{1-\delta})$$
for some $\delta>0$, then I have no idea which contradiction I'm supposed to get.

I tried the classical inequalities : $$\pi(x)\log(x)\geqslant\psi(x)\geqslant\sum_{x^{1-\eta}\leqslant p\leqslant x}\log(p)=(1-\eta)[\pi(x)+O(x^{1-\eta})]\log(x),$$
but I doubt it's leading me anywhere. Does anyone have any hint/idea ? The exercice doesn't give any besides some *trivia*.

Comment: Perhaps show that the error term $Li(x) -\frac{x}{\ln{x}}$ isn’t $o(x^{1-\delta})$ for any $\delta > 0$?

Comment: This is clearly L.W.A.

Comment: Do you know the LAAUA ? The League Against Abusive Use of Abbreviations :)... When I see in your title two unknowns abbreviations (unknown to me and to 98% of users of this site at least) like PNT and RH, I am under the impression that the fight against extended use of SMS style is close to be lost...

Comment: @Michael What is LWA (see my comment above) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie : L.W.A. = Loaded With Acronymns.  =)  I made L.W.A. up myself, did you make up LAAUA or is that somehow standard?  I like it better.

Comment: @Michael I understand we are on the same WL (wave length). LAAUA is just a creation of mine...

Comment: @JeanMarie TCT 98% ORDNR PNT & RH IPE.

Comment: @KCd Certainly FOH (full of humor) but SC (slightly cryptic).

Comment: "P.N.T." and "R.H." are some pretty standard abbreviations in Number Theory I heard... Not like if I were some newbie who didn't read the rules and said "plz solv my prbl im stuck" without having even tried anything... Also, your discussion is 1) against rules, and 2) satire shaming... At last, if I had written "Prime Number Theorem" and "Riemann Hypothesis" entirely, you'd have come and said I should have used a shorter title...

Comment: @Anthony Saint-Criq Don't take it like it. I like joking, and if you have feeled ashamed by my comment, I am very sorry. But understand that acronyms that are surely standard in a little community (sympathetic community moreover: I am a friend of some of its french members, like A. Gramain) but not in a wider one doesn't help information spreading.

Comment: @JeanMarie Okay, my bad then ! I'll know it's not well-received next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you proved, we have
$$
\pi (x) - \frac{x}{{\log x}} = \operatorname{Li}(x) + \mathcal{O}(x^{1 - \varepsilon }) - \frac{x}{{\log x}} = \operatorname{Li}(x) - \frac{x}{{\log x}} + \mathcal{O}(x^{1 - \varepsilon }).
$$
Now, it can be shown, using integration by parts, that
$$
\operatorname{Li}(x) = \frac{x}{{\log x}} + \frac{x}{{\log ^2 x}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\log ^3 x}}} \right).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\pi (x) - \frac{x}{{\log x}} = \frac{x}{{\log ^2 x}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\log ^3 x}}} \right) + \mathcal{O}(x^{1 - \varepsilon }) = \frac{x}{{\log ^2 x}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{x}{{\log ^3 x}}} \right) \notin o(x^{1 - \delta }).
$$